# Jenkins skips build shell command

Tags: shell, jenkins, command

I've made freestyle Jenkins Job. In the configurations I've added Build step execute shell with simple command echo "HELLO WORLD". When I build the job this shell command I think is never executed.I got no HELLO WORLD output there are also no shell errors and such. Can you tell me possible reasons why this is happening.

Comment: It will be helpful if you include the full output of your job run. Also what version of Jenkins are you using, and what platform are you running on?

Comment: Please go to last job run, click Console Output, and paste that to your answer

Comment: I fixed this. I just now use plugin Post build Plugin and this works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

What kind of shell are you using?

I've had the same kind of problem with **tcsh** - a command was never executed (not even echoed with the -x option). As it turned out, it was because there was no "newline" character after that command, and with tcsh that seems to be a problem.